# looping two arrays in React to return table

Tags: reactjs

I am facing a problem with having two arrays (of equal length). The arrays are in `store.indexData.buy`. The two arrays are then `buytime` and `buy_info`.

My problem here is that the for loop will only return one item. In this example the buy_info will contain 3 items. But only one will be returned. I assume that is because the for loop will not gather the items like .map() will do.

```js
const loopBuy = () => {
  if (store.indexData.buy == null)
    return;

  var elements = store.indexData.buy.map(buy => {
    console.log("Buy object "+ buy.buy_info);
    console.log("Buy time "+ buy.buytime);
    console.log("Len " +buy.buy_info.length);

    for (let i = 0; i < buy.buy_info.length; i++) {
      return (        
        <tr>
          <td>{buy.buytime[i]}</td> 
          <td>{buy.buy_info[i][0]}</td> 
          <td>{buy.buy_info[i][1]}</td> 
          <td>{buy.buy_info[i][2]}</td> 
          <td>{buy.buy_info[i][3]}</td>
        </tr>           
      );
    }        
  });

  return elements;
};
```

For completeness: Log information from the console log.

```
Buy object 1890.3807138888897,78.29174318003133,1890.0143445998149,1882.3823548789903,BEAR,1892.3184250000002,71.93138489200973,1892.212080497727,1889.8692777589233,BEAR,1881.171942857143,19.919471505372613,1896.5565850861638,1884.1295714370478,BULL buysell.js:21
Buy time 2020-02-21T09:35:00,2020-02-21T13:25:00,2020-02-21T16:05:00 buysell.js:22
Len 3
```

Comment: I don't really understand the problem, what seems to be the issue?

Comment: The return will not return the 3 items. It will only return one of them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your `elements` declaration to look like this:

```
var elements = store.indexData.buy.map(buy => {
  console.log("Buy object "+ buy.buy_info);
  console.log("Buy time "+ buy.buytime);
  console.log("Len " + buy.buy_info.length);

  buy.buy_info.map((item, i) => (        
    <tr>
      <td>{buy.buytime[i]}</td> 
      <td>{buy.buy_info[i][0]}</td> 
      <td>{buy.buy_info[i][1]}</td> 
      <td>{buy.buy_info[i][2]}</td> 
      <td>{buy.buy_info[i][3]}</td>
    </tr>           
  ))        
});
```

You were on the right track with identifying the problem. Using a for loop will stop the map upon the first return. That's why replacing it with a `map` is the right approach.